# Button CSS transition/animation hover problem

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I want to create a button which changes on hover. Here you can check it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fIcil2Xyky8DC2NRcfZBKXCMHk9gpat2/view?usp=sharing.

Here you can see my attempt: https://codepen.io/koravski/pen/BEvKRP

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.txt {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">Call to action</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

The problem is that when I hover it, it starts looping. It should be on the red rectangle so it won't loop.

If you have any suggestions it will be nice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what effect you are after but you're changing the size so when it shrinks you're not hovering on it any more.

I'd suggest a `transform` instead (two actually, one for the size and another for the position).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.txt {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: translateY(40px) scale(.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">Call to action</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

There are other issues but it depends on what this actually supposed to do.

In fact, you can do this with a single div.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.txt {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.txt:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.txt:hover:before {
  transform: translateY(40px) scale(.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">Call to action</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because whenever the button shrinks, your mouse is no longer hovering over it, so the animation comes back up and hits the box (causing it to trigger once again. I'd suggest using a pseudo element -

```
.box::before {
  background-color: red;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.box:hover.box::before {
   width: 50px;
   height: 5px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/aedenmurray/pen/XQodQj

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using background animation where you will need only one element:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.txt {
  color: #fff;
  padding:20px 50px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(red,red);
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-position:bottom center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:1s;
}
.txt:hover {
  background-size:20% 5%;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">Call to action</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap your `.box` and `.txt` in a container, and then when that container is hovered, do the transition. That way, your hover area isn't being resized - instead the contents are.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.txt {
  position:absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}


.container:hover > .box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="txt"> Call to action</div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[View Updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/Kxrl/pen/GLPZVY)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to apply the `:hover` to a surrounding element.
So you keep hovering over the element and just the included block will change.

FYI:

translate3d is used for better performance than normal `translateX`.
You could improve the code further. The red element could be a `::before` element, and you might want to attach `:focus`, too for better accessibility. And maybe use a `button` element.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
}

.btn-txt {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

.btn-box {
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn:hover .btn-box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0);
  top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <div class="btn-box"></div>
  <div class="btn-txt">Call to action</div>
</div>
```